# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable when sent a function as a function parameter

Tags: python, function, parameters, typeerror

I got an error message from this code

```
def make_lazy(*args):
    # implement here
    return args[0](args[1], args[2])
```

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

This code works in python 3.5.0, but python 2.7.6 shows the error.
How can I correct this code for python 2.7.6?

Comment: How are you invoking it?

Comment: `args[0]` is an `int` not a `function`.

Comment: I called it make_lazy(add, 2,3). add is another function. I want to call a function as a function parameter.

Comment: Like @Vishnu said you are returning args[0](args[1], args[2]) and args[0] is not a function.

Comment: I sent a function to args[0] as a parameter. In python 3.5.0, it works.

Comment: I should work if the first argument is a function.  Are you sure you haven't reused the function name as a variable?  It would be a lot easier to diagnose if you sent a complete example.

Comment: It also works in python 2.7.10.

Comment: @CristiFati Really? So is it just the problem of 2.7.6? How can I put a function as a function parameter in 2.7.6?

Comment: I strongly think that Tom Karzes's comment has the rootcause of your problem. I just tested in python 2.4.5 and it works there too. You might want to assemble a piece of code (containing just the 2 funcs and their call), and include it (together with the complete stacktrace) in the question.

Comment: There are two functions.  `def make_lazy(*args):
    # implement here
    return args[0](args[1], args[2])` and                                                         `def modding(a,b):
    return a%b` and I called `make_lazy(modding, 5,2)`

Comment: It still works. Any chance that you modify `args` before returning? Or `# implement here` is just a comment (and not a placeholder for other lines of code)?

Comment: @CristiFati I solved it by define another function in the  make_lazy that gets a args[0] as a parameter. It works. Thanks your answer.